# Why does this Jasmine spy cause an error?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have some code:

```
var bar = function() { ... };
var foo = function() { bar(); };
```

And a Jasmine test:

```
describe('foo', function() {
    it('calls bar', function() {
        spyOn(window, 'foo'); // this line causes an error
        spyOn(window, 'bar');
        foo();
        expect(bar).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

The commented line causes this error:

`Expected spy bar to have been called.`

Does Jasmine spying on `foo` somehow kill its native implementation? If I remove the commented line, the test passes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of this particular test to check whether or not invocation of `foo()` results in invocation of `bar()`. For the purpose, that...

```
it('calls bar', function() {
  spyOn(window, 'bar');
  foo();
  expect(bar).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

... is sufficient. Yes, you have to mock `bar` function, so instead of doing its job it'll just report about its call. But in no way you should mock `foo` with `spyOn` - you're *testing* the function, not the mock!

And if, for some reason, you just ought to have it observed, use `andCallThrough` spy method:

```
it('calls bar', function() {
  spyOn(window, 'foo').andCallThrough();
  spyOn(window, 'bar');
  foo();
  expect(bar).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

This way the mock will still be created (so you can use some of its methods - checking how many times the function is called, for example); the difference is calling the original function `foo` at the end of the mock's job.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. So spying on `foo` was completely unnecessary. And if I spy on `foo` and then call it (without `andCallThrough`), then I am actually calling a mock of it, not the function itself. Hence why `bar` was not called. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
spyOn(window, 'foo').andCallThrough()
```

Comment: Since I still have to spy on and then call `bar`, your line of code seems unnecessary.

Comment: Try adding some context to your code to help inform the person asking a question.